# `vagrant plugin update` causing `nokogiri` complaint after updating vagrant to 1.6.2

Tags: macos, vagrant

Just updated to vagrant 1.6.2

Ran `vagrant up` and got the following error

```
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is shown below.

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I ran `vagrant up --debug` and saw the following error message

```
ERROR vagrant: Vagrant experienced an error! Details:
ERROR vagrant: #<Vagrant::Errors::PluginLoadError: The plugins failed to load properly.     The error message given is shown below.

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
ERROR vagrant: The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is shown below.

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
ERROR vagrant: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.2/lib/vagrant.rb:265:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.2/lib/vagrant.rb:261:in `<top (required)>'
/Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.2/bin/vagrant:101:in `require'
/Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.2/bin/vagrant:101:in `<main>'
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is shown below.

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I then tried

```
vagrant plugin update
```

This produced the following complaint

```
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins, reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network issues. The error from Bundler is:

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I ran

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'
```

And this succeeded.

But it didn't solve the problem...

When I now run

```
vagrant plugin update
```

I still get the same error I got before installing `nokogiri`.

```
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins, reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network issues. The error from Bundler is:

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Run `vagrant up --debug` and see more output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I solved the problem for me at least.

I uninstalled vagrant 1.6.2 and installed [vagrant 1.6.1](http://www.vagrantup.com/download-archive/v1.6.1.html)

Comment: Not really a proper solution, but helped in my case too (OS X).

Answer (score 4):

This is a Vagrant issue and is being tracked in https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3769.